# Is there any user level command to check whether a kernel image is supporting NETLINK in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netlink

Without using any sample Netlink code is there any command or way to find out whether this kernel image is supporting Netlink or not.
For eg. NETLINK_GENERIC and NETLINK_ISCSI appeared in Linux 2.6.15.(netlink(7))
so how I can see which Netlink version it is supporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, afaik, check what parts of netlink is enabled/supported, such as NETLINK_GENERIC vs NETLINK_ISCSI, but as long as /proc is mounted, you can check if netlink is enabled at all:

- check if /proc/net/netlink exists
- check the available protocol families in /proc/net/protocols , if netlink is enabled there will be one line starting with the string "NETLINK", e.g.

  NETLINK    720     19      -1   NI       0   no   kernel      n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if any direct command is there, but whether `netlink` is supported/enabled you can check in the kernel's `.config` file. There are options like `CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK` which when selected enable the netlink support.

**EDIT**: And thereafter a simple `dmesg|grep -i netlink` can also give you an indication.